# How to display localized error messages in Super CSV

Tags: supercsv

My mother tongue is Spanish and I would like to know how to localize the error messages displayed by Super CSV's cell processors without compiling the source again.

Answer (score 0):

I know the idea for localizing error messages in Super CSV has been floating around for years now - it's just never had enough demand to warrant it (and not many other libraries support it either). I've used `String.format` for all exception messages throughout the code, so if we ever do add it it'll be relatively easy.

Your best bet (and you may or may not like this), is to copy the cell processors into your own project and modify the source to format the exceptions in Spanish (and just use your cell processors instead of the ones from Super CSV). That's probably a lot cleaner than trying to do some kind of mapping.