# Custom error message for a cell-processor in SuperCSV?

Tags: csv, supercsv

I'm using SuperCSV-2.3.1.

Is it possible to have a custom error msg to attach to a cell-processor, so when it fails validation, we get the custom msg in the exception?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only if you [write your own](http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/examples_new_cell_processor.html) cell processors (see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26698295/1068649))

Comment: I understand i could do it with custom cell-processor, but overriding 5-6 type of processors (for now, but who knows later), just for a custom message seems overkill, where as the cell-processor constructor could accept a msg instead, and be kept in the base processor.